# Regex match optional whole word in string

Tags: c#, regex

I am using Regex to perform some validation on a set of strings looking at salaries. The input string could look like one of the following:

£21220 to £24565
£21220 - £24565

I am looking to get the two numbers from this. Initially i am testing for when there is the 'to' in the middle but i get no matches. This is what i have so far:

£(\d*)\s^to$\s£(\d*)\z

Ideally i'd like to get it working so it can be either the '-' or the 'to' in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternation group:

```
£(\d+)\s*(?:-|to)\s*£(\d+)$
```

*The `$` is only needed if the value is at the end of the string* (your pattern contains `\z`, the very end of string anchor, that is why I used `$` here.)

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%c2%a3%28%5cd%2b%29%5cs*%28%3f%3a-%7cto%29%5cs*%c2%a3%28%5cd%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=%c2%a321220+to+%c2%a324565%0d%0a%c2%a321220+-+%c2%a324565&o=m).

[image]

**Pattern details**:

- `£`  - a pound currency sign
- `(\d+)` - (capturing) group 1 matching one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:-|to)` - either a `-` or `to` word
- `\s*`-  0+ whitespaces
- `£` - currency symbol
- `(\d+)` - capturing group 2 matching one or more digits
- `$` - end of string (use only if needed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use parentheses and the `|` character to define a capturing group with multiple possible matches within a single set (i.e. `(to|-)`) will match either "to" or "-" explicitly :

```
£\d+\s*(to|-)\s*£\d+
```

**Example**

[image]

**Pattern Breakdown**

- `£` - The pound sign.
- `\d+` - One or more digits.
- `\s*` - An optional number of whitespace.
- `(to|-)` - A group that will match either "to" or "-" explicitly.
- `\s*` - An optional number of whitespace.
- `£` - The pound sign.
- `\d+` - One or more digits.